# How to add cornerRadius to SwiftUI List Cell when using .listRowBackground in watchOS?

Tags: watchkit, swiftui

I'm trying to get the normal `List` on the watch with a `listRowBackground` image on each cell.

But when I set a image as the `listRowBackground` the corner radius from the standard `List` disappears (see below).

I've tried to set the `background` modified in the Cell-`View` itself, but that results in the same problem. 
Looking at the Visual View Debugger it seems that the background image, extends well beyond the cell itself.

```swift
struct ListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ListModel

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.model.items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: PlayerView(item: item)) {
                    ListCell(item: item).frame(height: 100)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Image(uiImage: item.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .opacity(0.7)
                )
            }
        }
        .listStyle(CarouselListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Today"))

    }
}

@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 6.0, *)
struct ListCell: View {
    var item: ListItem

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(self.item.length) MIN . \(self.item.category)")
                .font(.system(.caption, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.top, 2)
            Text(self.item.title)
                .font(.headline)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Image: with background image:

[image: w/ background image]

Image: without background image:

[image: w/o background image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the image to the ListCell instead of the ListRowBackground?  Could be done with a ZStack so the text goes on top of it.  I haven't used it on the watch yet, but with iOS, the ListRowBackground covers from side to side, where the "cell" sits on top of that.

Comment: The problem was here to get it to the right size. But combined with `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` this might have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I wrapped the image inside of a `GeometryReader` and added `clipped()` and `cornerRadius(10)` to the `GeometryReader`.

And add `buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to the `NavigationLink`.

```swift
    private func backgroundImage() -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { g in
            Image(<image>)
                .resizable()
                .blur(radius: 2)
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
        }
        .clipped()
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
```

and then add `.listRowBackground(self.backgroundImage())` to the `NavigationLink`.

Answer (score 16):

This works for me **Xcode 11.5**, Just add the `.clipped()` and              `.cornerRadius(10)` modifiers.

```
List {
         Text("Sample cell text")
            .listRowBackground(
               Color(.blue)
               .clipped()
               .cornerRadius(10))
      }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `clipped()` to the `NavigationLink`?